# Ficheiro ICS (ICalendar)

Tags: php

Estou a criar um ficheiro ics, que guarda as datas e os dados de um evento. Quero é que o ficheiro ao descarregar, esteja na raiz onde a página esteja a ser executada. E quando carrego a página, o ficheiro é logo descarregado, queria que fosse quando por exemplo clicar num link.

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['txtstart'])) 
{
    $txtstart = htmlentities($_GET['txtstart']);
}

if (isset($_GET['txtend'])) 
{
    $txtend = htmlentities($_GET['txtend']);
}

if (isset($_GET['txttitle'])) 
{
    $txttitle = htmlentities($_GET['txttitle']);
}

if (isset($_GET['txtdescription'])) 
{
    $txtdescription = htmlentities($_GET['txtdescription']);
}

if (isset($_GET['mois'])) 
{
    $mois = htmlentities($_GET['mois']);
}

if (isset($_GET['annee'])) 
{
    $annee = htmlentities($_GET['annee']);
}
$Filename = "file.ics";
header("Content-Type: text/Calendar"); //ics
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$Filename"); 

$DescDump = str_replace("\r", "=0D=0A=", $txtdescription); 

$dateStart=$annee.$mois.$txtstart."000000";
$vCalStart = date("Ymd\THi00", $dateStart); 

$dateEnd = $annee.$mois.$txtend."000000";
$vCalEnd = date("Ymd\THi00", $dateEnd); ?>

 BEGIN:VCALENDAR 
 VERSION:2.0
 PRODID:SSPCA Web Calendar 
 TZ:-07 
 BEGIN:VEVENT 
 SUMMARY:<?php echo $txttitle ."\n"; ?> 
 DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE: <?php echo $DescDump ."\n"; ?> 
 DTSTART:<?php echo $vCalStart ."\n"; ?> 
 DTEND:<?php echo $vCalEnd ."\n"; ?> 
 END:VEVENT 
 END:VCALENDAR
```

O ficheiro fica guardado na pasta dos downloads, e queria que ficasse na pasta raiz onde esta a página. E o abrir a página o ficheiro é logo descarregado, queria que fosse num link ou botão.

Comment: E qual é o problema?

Comment: O ficheiro fica guardado na pasta dos downloads, e queria que ficasse na pasta raiz onde esta a página. E o abrir a página o ficheiro é logo descarregado, queria que fosse num link ou butão.

Answer (score 0):

O facto de guardar nos downloads e não na raiz tem a ver com a configuração do seu *browser* e não com o PHP.

Para a parte do download com *link* é fácil basta colocares uma referência para esse PHP que colocaste ai:

```html
<a href='seuphpacima.php?suasvariaveis=valor'>download</a>
```